# mac osx server doesn't show on Add OSX server account

Tags: mac-osx-server, ical, osx-mountain-lion

I'm using mac osx server mountain lion and I'm new with mac OS 
Follow the instruction of the book "Mountain lion for dummies", I'm setting the iCal for the client. However I can't see my server appear on "Select nearby server" list. So I think, maybe I have done some wrong configuration. Anyone who knows about it, please help me 
many thanks

this the captured image
http://i182.photobucket.com/albums/x38/DNK90/iCal_zpse25f046b.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Select nearby server"

To my knowledge, this dialog uses Bonjour for service discovery. If machines are located on different VLANs or have a router between them then multicast traffic won't pass and auto-discovery won't function.

Try connecting to the server manually and see if it works.

Comment: thanks, after enter my domain server manually, I can add the calendar to others computers